# UISlider двигающий UIImageView

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

У меня есть горизонтальный UISlider и UIImageView превыщающая в два раза ширину view по горизонтали. Изначально бегунок слайдера и картинка установлены в среднее положение. По движению слайдера влево и вправо в соответствующие стороны пропорционально должна смещаться картинка, открывая для показа боковые части, которые при стартовом положении были скрыты. Пробую

```
slider.minimumValue = 0.0f;
slider.maximumValue = 1.0f;

 -(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender
 {
   [photoView setFrame:CGRectMake(sender.value, photoView.frame.origin.y, photoView.frame.size.width, photoView.frame.size.height)];
 }
```

и цепляю его к value changed слайдера в IB. Но при таком варианте картинка смещается один раз до финального положения и одним рывком а не плавно. Где я неправ, и каким образом все-таки можно реализовать такое поведение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы попробовал завернуть `setFrame`  в `animation`, например)

```
[UIImageView animateWithDuration:0.2f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^
    {
        [photoView setFrame:CGRectMake(sender.value, photoView.frame.origin.y, photoView.frame.size.width, photoView.frame.size.height)];
    }
    completion:nil];
```

Comment: А в чем разница между этим вариантом и тем который был представлен в теле вопроса?

Comment: Нужно правда еще допилить чтобы адекватно перемещалась картинка в зависимости от центра слайдера, но Ваш вариант работает

Comment: в Вашей реализации frame у photoView изменятеся как? просто перерисовывается в новых координатах и получается рывок. 
я не знаю как точно работает animation, но думаю что он разбивает расстояние перемещения на какое-то множество промежуточных шагов  и проходит по ним. 
как в тетрадке рисовать на каждой странице рисунок с мелкими изменениями, а потом листать. вот и вся анимация)

Comment: Благодарю за комментарий!